# textarea takes up too much height

Tags: jquery, html, css, textarea

My HTML is just a textarea within the body.

my JavaScript (with jquery) is:

```
$(function()
{
    $("body").height($(window).height())
})
```

my CSS is:

```
textarea
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    resize: none;
    background-color: red;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
}
textarea:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
body
{
    background-color: #DBDBDB;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why there is a scrollbar (the textarea isn't small enough to fit within the window's height)?

Comment: Why do you need the JS? I doesn't make much sense what you're doing there. Try setting up an example at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Isn't there a problem if you're setting the width both by percentage in CSS and by a function in JS? I'm not sure...

Comment: Because you are setting textarea height property to 100%. Why?

Comment: I want the textarea to fill the webpage guys

Comment: If the body is 100% of the screen, why wouldn't 100% of that be the same

Comment: I installed Chrome on Ubuntu just to test your use case more.  I have updated my answer with a solution that worked for me.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks guys, i didnt know stackoverflow rocked this much. i have to wait till the morning to try negative margin and, um, lineheight. I'll have learn more about these "unique" changes. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

It was because of the **line-height** property of the body.. Set it to 0..

```
body
{
    line-height: 0;
}
```

If you do not want to do this you can set the textarea  `height:99%;`   instead

[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RVWvY/)

Answer (score 0):

Though it is not the best solution, I have just applied a little trick and it's working for all sizes of monitors!

```
 $(function()
{
    var height = $(window).height() -5;
    var width = $(window).width() - 5;
    $('#someId').css('height', height);
    $('#someId').css('width', width);
});
```

CSS:

```
   textarea
    {
        resize: none;
        background-color: red;
        border: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        outline: none;
    }
    textarea:focus
    {
        outline: none;
    }
    body
    {
        background-color: #DBDBDB;
        margin: 0;
    }​
```

See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kaidul/6t9LP/)

Answer (score -1):

The reason you are seeing a scrollbar is because the textarea still has margin.  To fix this, set a margin of 0 on the textarea.

Revised CSS:

```
textarea
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    resize: none;
    background-color: red;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
textarea:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
body
{
    background-color: #DBDBDB;
    margin: 0;
}
```

EDIT:

The code above works for browsers not doing "unique" changes to elements.  Chrome apparently is somehow added extra height.  To fix this for Chrome specifically you will had to add negative margin to the element (Example: margin: -2px 0).  Also, my recommendation is to only add the negative margin when Chrome is the browser (Search on how to do this).

Comment: the textarea already had no margin in google chrome--(didn't change anything)

Comment: Worked for me on Firefox in Ubuntu

Comment: Updated it with an Edit explaining how you can get this working on Chrome

Answer (score -1):

If all you have on page is a textarea, set hight for body and html tag

CSS:

```
html,body{ height:100%}
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/SWLsH/1

EDIT: textarea height of 100% doesn't account for the border which causes body scroll bar. Make height 99%